# how to put outputs in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have printed  a result  like:
-49.0248
-15.9876 
-60.1683 
-48.9527 
-13.2561 
-54.0585 
14.2175 
-39.5988 
-28.0246 
-42.4494 
-39.7153 
-54.3654. 
I want to put this in an array. I have used np.array(result).But it is giving me the same answer not the array.

Comment: I'm not used to NumPy, but i guess you could use `list comprehensions`.

Answer (score 0):

To "put" data into an array, you use a method called `append`, for example:

`my_array = []
for x in range(300):
    my_array.append(x)`

The above code will `append` each number up to 300 into `my_array`.

I'm not sure how you're coming up with your numbers, can you reply with your code please and I'll try to help as much as I can, thanks.